# Fullpage.js sometimes does not responsive on mobiles

Tags: jquery, css, fullpage.js

1. Sometimes Fullpage.js does not behave responsive on the mobile device. I do not know an exact way to reproduce the fault.

Fault involves following:

When page is loaded sometimes on the mobile browser it does not arrange itself to the screen to show all content on one screen.

2. In the Apple-site Demo the content is not showed in one screen width, vertical and horizontal. In no other demo this prolem exists.

Viewing on General Mobile Discovery Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes Fullpage.js does not behave responsive on the mobile device. I do not know an exact way to reproduce the fault.

You might be forgetting to add the plugin initialization inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` function.

> In the Apple-site Demo the content is not showed in one screen width, vertical and horizontal. In no other demo this prolem exists.

If you read the text [in that demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html) you will easily find the following statement:

> This is, of course, just a demo. I didn't want to spend much time on
>   it. **Don't expect it to work perfectly in all kind of screens.** It has
>   been designed to work on 1180px width or over on modern browsers with
>   CSS3.